# Image Deduplication

Tags: images, image-processing

I'm looking for a program that will help me remove duplicate imagess from a bunch of folders. Preferably free.

It has to be able to do:

- Similarity matching (e.g. find images that look alike)
- Tell me when 2 images are binary equals or in what way they are different (size, dimension, date).
- Work with large images/galleries (10mb+, 10000+)
- View images side by side for comparison.
- Handle unicode.
- Create galleries to which you can add more files later.
- Handle groups of similar images.
- Mark images as "unlike".

I need to process ~100,000 files. Every bit of automation and UI convenience matters.

Things I've looked at:

- [imagededup](https://github.com/idealo/imagededup) is a HELL NO.
- [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page) doesn't support large images and has a poor UI.
- [Duplicate finder](https://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo-download.html) is not that bad functionally, but is pathetically slow and stateless, making it impossible to use.

Answer (score 1):

You did not state windows or Linux, so we will assume windows (but you are covered just about anyway).

DupeGuru has been very effective in the past.
https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWqVkhfehNg

Answer (score 0):

I've found DigiKam works for this, though it's also horribly slow, with bad UI, and seems to randomly crash/hang on me.